# Written Draft Cheque

Tags: check, deposits

A friend has written a draft cheque in my name in US dollars can I deposit it in any bank in the world? Was this legal in form? About how many days is the clearing time? Is there any charges for this transaction?

Comment: "Draft cheque" in my understanding is the same as a "cashier's check" in US terminology. Assuming that's what you mean, your friend cannot write such a check unless your friend is a bank rather than a person. Could you clarify this question?

Answer (score 1):

> A friend has written a draft cheque in my name in US dollars

Not sure what you mean by this? You friend has written this on a piece of paper? If so this may only be honoured that the specific Bank and will not go through any standard clearing. Some other Bank's may agree to send this on behalf of you ... but not all Banks would want to do this, its not standard.

If you friend has written a cheque on a proper check book, then yes you can deposit this in *MOST* Bank [in *MOST* country]. Not all Banks provide clearing of Foreign cheque. Depending on country / bank it takes anywhere between 1 to 3 months for funds to be credited. There may be some regulatory paperwork to be completed in few countries.

Comment: You may also be subject to currency conversion fees unless you open a dollar-denominated account, and/or subject to limits on how money can be transferred out of your friend's country.